# Building and Installing Lua 5.2.0 on Mac os x Lion

Tags: macos, build, lua, installation

I have read instructions on a lot of sites on how to build/install Lua 5.2.0 on a mac os x Leopard, not Lion.

So my question is: "How do I get from installing and / or building Lua on my mac, to programming code on my computer?"

Comment: I actually need the instructions today please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from the [Lua FAQ](http://www.lua.org/faq.html#1.1):

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.0.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.2.0.tar.gz
cd lua-5.2.0
make macosx test install
```

You need a C compiler. Get Xcode if you haven't yet.

This works in both Leopard and Lion (and other versions of Mac OS X).

Comment: Thank you very much, but at a certain moment it gets an error. This is what it says:                                                    mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/include: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/lib: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/man: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/share: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/lib: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: I'm sorry if it's to messed up for you.

Comment: Oh and I must note I have another coding program called 'CodeRunner'.

Comment: To install you need permissions. So do `make macosx ; sudo make install`. You'll need to give the administrator password.

Comment: It does work, but it says "install: /usr/local/bin/lua: chmod: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install] Error 71" ((Thanks anyway so far))

Comment: Any thoughts on how to build a 32-bit version on OSX?

Comment: Works fine for me on Lion.  Thanks for the tip as I was struggling with getting it to work using homebrew.

Comment: @Richard, try `make macosx MYCFLAGS=-m32 MYLDFLAGS=-m32`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe before doing that, you should go in terminal and type 
chmod a+x 
Then it should allow the file to run, and without that chmod error.